# Media upload filesize(): stat failed for uploads error Laravel - TwitterOauth

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-oauth

I am using Abraham's https://twitteroauth.com/  package for sending twitter messages from Laravel App.

Also I scheduled messages with Laravel task scheduling.
I also need to send media twitter message with this package. It works normally. But it does not work with laravel task schedule console command.

My twitter message sending code is like this:

```
                $screenshot = $this->takeScreenShot();
                $media = $this->twitter->upload('media/upload', array('media' => "uploads/$screenshot", 'media_type' => 'image/png'), true);
                $parameters = [
                    'status' => $twitterMsg,
                    'media_ids' => implode(',', [$media->media_id_string])
                ];
                $result = $this->twitter->post('statuses/update', 

$parameters);
```

It throws this error:

```
filesize(): stat failed for uploads/screenshots_1620116807.png

at vendor/abraham/twitteroauth/src/TwitterOAuth.php:417
  413▕             'shared',
  414▕         ];
  415▕         $base = [
  416▕             'command' => 'INIT',
➜ 417▕             'total_bytes' => filesize($parameters['media']),
  418▕         ];
  419▕         $allowed_parameters = array_intersect_key(
  420▕             $parameters,
  421▕             array_flip($allowed_keys),

    +3 vendor frames
4   app/Services/TwitterService.php:219
    Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth::upload()
```

How can I solve this error for console task command?

Thanks

Comment: The error message most likely means, it does not find the file under the path you have given. The execution context within the task scheduler is probably a different one, might have a different working directory, than when you run scripts that create the normal frontend output. Try and give a full absolute path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe because of the relative path you provided as `uploads/screenshots_1620116807.png` on `media`. Try to pass to the absolute path of your media, e.g. via `storage_path` or `public_path` helper methods:

```php
$media = $this->twitter->upload('media/upload', [
    'media' => public_path("uploads/$screenshot"),
    'media_type' => 'image/png',
], true);
```

Comment: Actually It is not stored in  storage path. I used to store in public path.

Comment: @tcetin no different, use `public_path` instead.

Comment: You are trying to set this change to  twitter package. I updated the question. Please take a look at.